# laravel phpunit how to determine which method to run

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I created a UserTest class that will be used to test many user related methods and everytime a run `php vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit` it always goes through all the methods which is not practical , i want to know if it's pôssible to run a test on a specific method .
Thank you

Comment: https://phpunit.de/manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  To run on a specific method you can use the filter flag.

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter name_of_the_method
```

You can also group files together using your phpunit.xml file.  Look for the tag testsuite and create a second one.

```
<testsuite name="API">
    <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/ApiTests</directory>
</testsuite>
```

Now, you can use the "testsuite" flag to run tests in that folder only.

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite API
```

Also note the "suffix" in the directory of your testsuite.  This refers to what the file must end with.  You can filter the files that will run the test further by adjusting your naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Just Found an answer i needed to user `--filter` then the name of the class then the name of the method like this

```
php vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit --filter UserTest::testinput
```